# Is there a way to allow your bot to follow announcement channels for other servers through a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

My bot uses discord.py, is there a way to code it to allow it to automatically follow an announcement channel for other servers to your server through a command?

Comment: You can do on_message and send every message in that channel as soon as it is sent in the "followed" channel. I don't think it's possible to make a channel follow this announcement channel.

Answer (score 1):

I've latterly been tiring to figure this same issue. I've looked everywhere and could find nothing on this topic. I finally asked the owner of DYNO bot how he did it. The code you're looking for is this following I believe.

```
announcementChannel = client.get_channel(962525150962647044)
await announcementChannel.follow(destination = addToChannel, reason=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what your asking, but you can check if a message is the message that a channel is following another, by doing `message.type == discord.MessageType.channel_follow_add`

Here are some useful links:

[on_message event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)

[MessageType.channel_follow_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.MessageType.channel_follow_add)

You cant follow channels with bots, if this is what you mean instead.