# discord.py discord bot following anouncement channel

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to write a code that allows the bot to follow a specific notification channel and send notifications to the channel set by the user when I use a command in discord.py. Can you help me?

i tried chatgpt but i couldnt understand and also it didint worked.

Comment: Do these help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386189/is-there-a-way-to-allow-your-bot-to-follow-announcement-channels-for-other-serve and https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.WebhookType.channel_follower